# jQuery - Insert new row after a specific row in $.ajax call

Tags: jquery, html-table, insert, row

I need to insert several rows of data in the success function of an $.ajax call to a PHP database query.

Here's what I've come up with so far (It doesn't work and I get a Syntax error in the console "Unexpected String" on the $.each() line):

```
// This is the checkbox element in the row that was clicked on
//$('#tblMovieList tbody tr').find('td input.chkDeleteMovie[value="' + movieID + '"]').parent()

console.log('row html: ' + $('#tblMovieList tbody tr').find('td input.chkDeleteMovie[value="' + movieID + '"]').parent().parent().next().html());

//actorID, actorFirstName, actorLastName

$('#tblMovieList tbody tr').find('td input.chkDeleteMovie[value="' + movieID + '"]').parent().parent().after('<tr id="actorsForMovie' + movieID + '">' +
    '<td colspan="2"></td>' +
    '<td colspan="8">' +
        '<table id="tblActorsForMovie">' +

            $.each(data,function(index,element) {

            '<tr>' +
                '<td>' +
                    'actorID: ' + element['actorID'] + ', name: ' + element['actorFirstName'] + ' ' + element['actorLastName'] +
                '</td>' +
            '</tr>' +
            });
        '</table>' +
    '</td>' +
'</tr>';
);
```

What I need to do is insert a row that contains the json data from the php script *after* the row that has a checkbox with a value set to a specific movie ID.

The console.log line correctly locates the row that is **after** the row that I need to append the new row to. (Did that make sense?)

So, the selector that has the after() function is correct. I'm just not sure how exactly to insert that new row while iterating through the json data.

How do I need to do that?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**
The final structure of the row that is to be inserted should look like this:

```
</tr><!-- closing tag of existing row that the new row is being appended to -->
<tr id="actorsForMovie">
    <td colspan="10"> <!-- There are 10 columns in the "parent" table -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    [actor data]
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    [actor data]
                </td>
            </tr>
            ... etc for additional rows/actors
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr> <!-- Opening tag of the existing row that **was** immediately after the row being appended to -->
```

I have created [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/CDaEN/) for anyone to take a crack at helping me figure this out. No matter what I've tried, the inserted table 1) Never gets wrapped in the  and  tags to make it work with the "parent" table, and 2) the inserted table *always* only gets put in the area of the first cell in the rest of the table.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this adjusted so the table gets inserted into the row properly?

Comment: Note. Since my original post and chead's original answer, I've added a lot of clarifying information and a link to a jsFiddle I set up for this. I'd really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance...

Comment: I've added a LOT of info here. Hopefully this is enough for someone to help me out soon. If more info is needed, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[chead23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958182/jquery-insert-new-row-after-a-specific-row-in-ajax-call/14958510#14958510) got me on the right track, so while waiting for additional responses on this I continued to look for a solution.

Here is the final working code:

```
 var actorRow = '',
    actorsTableRow = '',
    $row = $('#tblMovieList tbody tr').find('td input.chkDeleteMovie[value="' + movieID + '"]').parent().parent();

    // Add each actor as its own table row
    $.each(data, function(index,element) {
        actorRow += '<tr>' +
            '<td>' +
                element['actorFirstName'] + ' ' + element['actorLastName'] +
            '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    });

    // Build the parent table's row around the actor rows
    actorsTableRow += '<tr id="actorsForMovie">' +
        '<td colspan="11">' +
            '<table>' +
                actorRow +
            '</table>' +
        '</td>' +
    '</tr>';

    // Add the new row to the table immediately after the movie row that was clicked on
    $row.after(actorsTableRow);
```

As you can see by the comments in the code, I just put everything into string variables and then added that to the parent table. Chead's attempt at using `$.append()` and `$.wrap()` seems to have unnecessarily complicated things. Perhaps those are technically quicker to use, but as I wasn't getting any additional help, this is what I came up with (it works - that's all I needed! :P).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to concatenate the string with the function `$.each()`.

If I understand correctly I think you want to do something like:

```
var row = $('#tblMovieList tbody tr').find('td input.chkDeleteMovie[value="' + movieID + '"]').parent().parent();

 var afterItem = $('<table id="tblActorsForMovie"></table>');

 $.each(data, function (index, element)
 {
     afterItem.append('<tr><td>' + 'actorID: ' + element['actorID'] + ', name: ' + element['actorFirstName'] + ' ' + element['actorLastName'] + '</td></tr>');
 });

 row.after(afterItem.wrap('<td colspan="2"></td><td colspan="8">'));
```

Comment: chead, That's close, but not quite. I think you understand what I'm trying to do, but what is happening with your code is a table is getting inserted after the correct row, but the table isn't wrapped inside a set of <tr><td> tags to make it the next row in the parent #tblMovieList table, which is what I'm assuming the last line of your code is supposed to do. (By the way, is that you, Coothead, who I see so often at HTML Forums?)

Comment: I've added the "Additional Info" that will hopefully clarify what exactly I'm trying to accomplish. I'm still fiddling with this and I'm pretty sure the problem with chead's code is in the "wrap()" line.